# Jekyll liquid if statement confusion

Tags: html, if-statement, logic, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to make a if statement work according to my markdown post's liquid header where if a variable is set to true, do a thing, else and if it doesn't exist do the other thing. Just can't seem to get it to work properly.

I've tried changing the if statement to `{% unless %}`. trying different combos of `!= false` and swapping the image code around.

```
{% capture banner %}{{ page.banner }}{{ post.banner }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture no-border %}{{ page.no-border }}{{ post.no-border }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture title %}{{ page.title }}{{ post.title }}{% endcapture %}

{% if banner != "" %}
    {% if no-border == true %}
    <img class="center no-border" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
    {% else %}
    <img class="center" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

I expected to see: if `no-border` is set to true in markdown file liquid portion, remove border of banner image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your capture tag, without `page.no-border` or `post.no-border`, returns an empty string, which evaluates to true because all values in liquid are truthy, except for `false` and `nil`. Try this instead (or something like it) :

```
{% capture banner %}{{ page.banner }}{{ post.banner }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture title %}{{ page.title }}{{ post.title }}{% endcapture %}

{% if page.banner or post.banner %}
    {% if page.no-border or post.no-border %}
        <img class="center no-border" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
    {% else %}
        <img class="center" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

This is all untested and you could accomplish it a few different ways.

Edit: Clarification

### Detailed Explanation:

`capture` is a function. It evaluates whatever is inside, and stores it as a string in a variable. If the contents are `nil` (nothing), then it returns an empty string (`""`).

In programming, every value is considered 'truthy' or 'falsy'. This means that (among other things) when placed in an `if` statement, truthy values will execute the statement and falsy values won't. Take an integer value of 1 for example; in most languages, this is a truthy value, so

```
if 1
  puts 'hello world'
end
```

will print 'hello world' to the console. `nil` is generally a falsy value, so

```
if nil
  puts 'hello world'
end
```

will do nothing.

Exactly which values are truthy or falsy depend on the programming language. **In Liquid, everything is truthy except for `nil` and `false`**. `capture` always returns a string, and all strings, even empty ones, are truthy.

If you write this:

```
{% if "" %}
<img class="center no-border" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
{% else %}
<img class="center" src="{{ banner }}" alt="{{ title }}"/><br/>
{% endif %}
```

You will always get the no-border version. Replace that `if` statement with `if "true"`, or `if true` and you will get the same result.

Comment: well that seems to work. why wouldn't the capture tag work if it's supposed to pull from the same page and post tags?

Comment: I added a detailed explanation to the answer. Hopefully it helps!